# Как более экономично и/или правильно использовать CSS стили

Tags: javascript, css

Есть вэб приложение у которого планируется реализация кроссплатформенного резинового дизайна, причем при уменьшении экрана до телефонного CSS стили  сильно меняются, в связи с этим вопрос, как правильно использовать стили? У меня два предположения - первое это использовать медиа запросы (но их будет оооочень много) или второй вариант сделать CSS файл для телефонов и менять его javascript-ом .

Просвятите чайника по этому вопросу пожалуйста (п.с. не использую фреймворки и пишу на чистом js и php)

Comment: Я за медиа-запросы. Удобно, гибко, эффективно.

Comment: Медиа-запросы. Все так делают. И потом, что значит - очень много?

Comment: Много это я имею ввиду что допустим в медиа запросе до 500 px будет почти весь css файл изменен, пугает такое объемное дублирование кода

Comment: @Чайник ну и что. Сколько строк всего?

Comment: 452 строк в одном файле, еще пара по 200